# How can i insert a value in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys its possible that i can insert a value from my jquery.

this is my code of html and jquery please help me thank you in advance!!!

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#oroom").blur(function() {
      var oroom = $("#oroom").val();
      var capa = $("#rcapa").val();
      if (oroom.lenght == capa.lenght) {
        $("#rcapa").html("Capacity of 1 - 16 person");
      }
    });
  }); < /script>
```

```html
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left:100px;">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    Occupied Rooms:
    <select class="form-control" name="room" id="oroom">
      <option>Occupied Room</option>
      <option id="1room">1 Room</option>
      <option>2 Rooms</option>
      <option>3 Rooms</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left:100px;">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    Rooms Capacity:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rcapa" disabled>
  </div>
```

Comment: there is typo error `lenght ` it should be `length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.html() use to set/get the HTML content while .val() use to get/assign the value to control

```
$("#rcapa").html("Capacity of 1 - 16 person"); //insert as a HTML
```

use this one

```
$("#rcapa").val("Capacity of 1 - 16 person"); // assign the value to the control
```

Answer (score 2):

use `val()` instead of `html()` for input elements

replace

```
$("#rcapa").html("Capacity of 1 - 16 person");
```

by

```
$("#rcapa").val("Capacity of 1 - 16 person");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$("#rcapa").val("Capacity of 1 - 16 person");
```

`.html()` will set its `innerHTML` with the passed value. Since `input` element is a `void` element(it cannot contain any elements as its child), the `innerHTML` will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : Use `.val()` instead of `.html()`

```
$("#rcapa").val("Capacity of 1 - 16 person");
```

More information on

**[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** 
**[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**